# If $f(x)$ is $1$–$1$, must $g(f(x))$ be $1$–$1$?

Tags: functions

Say $f$ is $1$–$1$, and both $f$ and $g$ are from $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. Does $g$ have to be $1$–$1$? What about $f \circ  g$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It helps readability to format questions/answers using MathJax (see FAQ). I did this one as an example. Also, what are your thoughts on the problem? Regards

Comment: All you know about $g$ is that it is a function from $N \to N$. So why would $g(x)$ have to be $1-1$? (To "prove" your answer, you could try coming up with a counterexample.)

Comment: My thought is that letting g(x) = a for some constant a is a countereample. does that work?

Comment: I made a guess and edited $N$ to $\mathbb N$. People usually don't write $N$ for some arbitrary set.

Comment: If one reads the title, I think the OP is asking if $g\circ f$ is one to one, not if $g$ must be one to one.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $f(n) = n$, $g(n) = k$, $k$ a constant. $f$ is one-to-one, but $g$ is not, nor is $g \circ f$ or $f \circ g$.

Answer (score 0):

An easy counter example is to let $f$ be the identity function, i.e. $f(x) = x$. Then $f(g(x)) = g(x)$ for all $g$ so this would mean that all functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ are injective.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't imposed any conditions on $g$. So it can do as it likes.

Your first question is analogous to: "Rover is a Labrador. Rover and Pooch are both dogs. Does Pooch have to be a Labrador?" Well, quite obviously, no!

**Let's consider the case where $f$ and $g$ are both one-to-one:**

If $f$ is one-to-one then we have $f(m) = f(n)$ if and only if $m=n$. If $g$ is one-to-one then $g(p)=g(q)$ if and only if $p=q$. Consider the composite $f \circ g$. This is given by $(f \circ g)(m) = f(g(m))$. To show that $f \circ g$ is one-to-one, we must show that $(f \circ g)(m) = (f \circ g)(n)$ if and only if $m=n$.

Assume that $(f \circ g)(m) = (f \circ g)(n)$. By definition we have $f(g(m)) = f(g(n))$. Since $f$ is one-to-one $f(g(m)) = f(g(n))$ if and only if $g(m) = g(n).$ Since $g$ is one-to-one $g(m) = g(n)$ if and only if $m=n.$ Hence $(f \circ g)(m) = (f \circ g)(n)$ if and only if $m=n.$